# List a current posts' taxonomy terms in a widget in Wordpress

Tags: taxonomy, widgets

I would very much like to know if there is a widget that exists that would let me show the current page's associated taxonomy terms (preferably hierarchically) in a widget.

For example, if the current post has a Taxonomy term "Tom Hanks" in the Taxonomy of "Actor", the widget would list "Actor" then "Tom Hanks". Even though there are many other actors in the taxonomy of "Actors", only the ones from the current page, are listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple conversion of the Taxonomy terms list plugin to a widget:

```
class WPSE_5394_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct( 'wpse5394_widget', 'Taxonomy Terms List' );
    }

    public function widget( $sidebar_args, $widget_options )
    {
        if ( ! is_single() ) {
            // I don't think we can display anything sensible on a page with multiple posts
            return;
        }

        $output = $sidebar_args['before_widget'];

        // If we want to use this we should provide a way to set the title
        if ( ! empty( $widget_options['title'] ) ) {
            $output = $sidebar_args['before_title'] . $widget_options['title'] . $sidebar_args['after_title'];
        }

        // This is the meat of the function: get the taxonomies we want to display, and get the terms for each taxonomy
        $taxonomy_names = apply_filters( 'wpse5394_taxonomies', array_fill_keys( get_taxonomies(), true ) );
        $taxonomy_terms = '';

        foreach ( $taxonomy_names as $taxonomy_name => $dummy ) {
            $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy_name );
            $before = apply_filters( 'wpse5394_taxonomy_before', '<p>' . $taxonomy->label . ': ', $taxonomy );
            $sep = apply_filters( 'wpse5394_taxonomy_sep', ', ' );
            $after = apply_filters( 'wpse5394_taxonomy_after', '</p>' );
            $terms = get_the_term_list( 0, $taxonomy_name, $before, $sep, $after );
            if ( $terms ) {
                $taxonomy_terms .= $terms;
            }
        }

        if ( ! $taxonomy_terms ) {
            // No taxonomy terms will be displayed - don't display the widget
            return;
        }
        $output .= $taxonomy_terms;

        $output .= $sidebar_args['after_widget'];

        echo $output;
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpse5394_widgets_init' );
function wpse5394_widgets_init()
{
    register_widget( 'WPSE_5394_Widget' );
}
```

Most options can be set via filters, like the taxonomies you want to display:

```
add_filter( 'wpse5394_taxonomies', 'wpse5394_taxonomies' );
function wpse5394_taxonomies( $taxonomies )
{
    unset( $taxonomies['category'] );
    return $taxonomies;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jan - this is perfect - spot on. In your code it says "we should provide a way to set the title." I asume you mean in the widget control panel. The question i have is that all the widgets tutorials I have found use register_widget_control - but that doesn't seem to work with your code. Can you point me to some link of how to add the controls so i can make the title and other things be configurable?

Comment: @cmurockstar: I'm glad it worked for you. The `register_widget_control()` function is deprecated since WP 2.8. Fortunately the new [Widget API documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets_on_2.8.2B) code example contains exactly what you need. Try to copy the `update()` and `form()` functions and it should work. Did you know that [you can "accept" answers by clicking the empty checkbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? We both get a reputation increase from it, allowing you to do more on the site.

Comment: no i didn't. I am completely new to stackechange and stackoverflow. And I wish I had known about these a long time ago. So CHECK!

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong you want something like this:
there is a plugin which displays the custom taxonomy which is there selected for the corresponding post
but it will display below the post not in the widget area

you can have a look at it
[Taxonomy terms List](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-terms-list/)

this will display all the terms of taxonomies which you have selected

Comment: Almost, but basically IN the Widget area. So Taxonomy term list, but sitting in the widget area.

Comment: try google on how to call a function in widget area, i dont think it will be helpful in widget area, cause your post will change so everytime your widget also has to change, so in that sense you have to edit the function of plugin again, which will be a hectic work,
for displaying it next to post you can use this plugin, or try to code it

Comment: Hi Ntechi - did you forget a link? You wrote "you can use this plugin" but no reference to which plugin you mean.

Comment: i mean if you want to display the custom taxonomies exactly after the post then use Taxonomy terns list, the link is in my original answer